# SQL - Sum of query not true

Tags: sql

I have this query;

```
    SELECT l.Name, COALESCE(SUM(A.Count), 0) AS A, COALESCE(SUM(B.Count), 0) AS B
    FROM List l
    LEFT JOIN A ON A.Name = l.Name
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.Name = l.Name
    GROUP BY l.Name
    ORDER BY l.Name
```

And query results not true.

Sum of Product3 in Table A is not true.

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sum separately for A and B and then combine results:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(A) AS A, MAX(B) AS B
FROM (
  SELECT l.Name, SUM(A.Count) AS A, 0 AS B
  FROM List l
  LEFT JOIN A ON A.Name = l.Name
  GROUP BY l.Name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT l.Name, 0 AS A, SUM(B.Count)AS B
  FROM List l
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.Name = l.Name
  GROUP BY l.Name) sub
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/6)**

Answer (score 1):

You should be aggregating the `A` and `B` tables in separate subqueries:

```
SELECT
    l.Name,
    COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) AS a_cnt,
    COALESCE(b.cnt, 0) AS b_cnt
FROM List l
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, SUM(Count) AS cnt
    FROM A
    GROUP BY Name
) a
    ON l.Name = a.name
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, SUM(Count) AS cnt
    FROM B
    GROUP BY Name
) b
    ON l.Name = b.name;
```

The problem with your current approach is that the double join to the `A` and `B` tables is likely resulting in double counting.  By using separate subqueries we avoid this problem.

Comment: I need sum.Not Count

Answer (score 0):

In your original question on this subject, I suggested correlated subqueries.  These are probably the easiest way to accomplish what you want:

```
select l.name,
       (select sum(a.count)
        from a
        where a.name = l.name
       ) as a,
       (select sum(b.count)
        from b
        where b.name = l.name
       ) as b
from list l;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check null values before sum() not after.

```
 SELECT l.Name, SUM(COALESCE(A.Count, 0)) AS A, SUM(COALESCE(B.Count, 0)) AS B
    FROM List l
    LEFT JOIN A ON A.Name = l.Name
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.Name = l.Name
    GROUP BY l.Name
    ORDER BY l.Name
```